# This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects SSIS VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools

I have isntalled VS2019 and installed SSDT from installer but I still get error when trying to open SSIS projects:
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them.

I have also installed Analysis services from nuget and EF6.

In the installer , I can see SSDT is marked as installed.
Restarted both VS and pc.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install the additional Visual Studio Extensions?

- [Analysis Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects)
- [Integration Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects)
- [Reporting Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio)

Comment: I wasn't and after installed everything, works now so thank you.